# Why my state is not re-rendering when my state changes in this reducer in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

This does the logic but my component is not re rendering

```
 case CONSTANTS.DELETE_CARD:
      const newStateInit = state.map((list) => {
        if (list.id === action.payload.listID) {
          let delcardIndex = list.cards.findIndex((card) => {
            return card.id === action.payload.cardID;
          });
          list.cards.splice(delcardIndex, 1);
        }
        return list;
      });
      localStorage.setItem("todo-list", JSON.stringify(newStateInit));
      return [...newStateInit];
```

Comment: I think you need to return something like this. return {...state, newStateInit}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue lies in the fact that even though the state is a new array reference, the specific list element is not, and is in fact, being mutated with the `splice` (*recall that `splice` operates on the array in place*). Spreading `newStateInit` into a new array is superfluous since `Array.prototype.map` already returns a new array reference.

When updating state you typically need to also shallow copy any nested state that is being updated. Map the existing state into `newStateInit`, and while mapping previous `list` element objects when the `list.id` matches the payload, shallow copy the `list` element and use `Array.prototype.filter` to return a new `cards` array where the current `card.id` ***doesn't*** match the id you are trying to remove.

```
case CONSTANTS.DELETE_CARD:
  const { cardID } = action.payload;
  const newStateInit = state.map((list) => {
    if (list.id === action.payload.listID) {
      return {
        ...list,
        cards: list.cards.filter(card => card.id !== cardID),
      };
    }
    return list;
  });
  localStorage.setItem("todo-list", JSON.stringify(newStateInit));
  return newStateInit;
```